# How to create a mongoengine connection with ssh?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, mongoengine, pymongo-3.x

I'm trying to create a connection and add a document with mongoengine through an SSH tunnel.

A successful attempt with pymongo can be seen below, I simply want something similar with mongoengine. :-)

```
from auth import *
import pymongo
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (HOST_IP, HOST_PORT),
    ssh_username = SSH_USER,
    ssh_password = SSH_PASS,
    remote_bind_address = ('localhost', 27017)
    )

server.start()

client = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1', server.local_bind_port)
db = client[MONGO_DB]
db.authenticate(MONGO_USER, MONGO_PASS)
coll = db.queue_db
coll.insert({"testFile42":43})

server.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoengine.connect(
    db=DB_NAME,
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=server.local_bind_port
)
```